# создания массива python

Tags: python

Начал изучать Python и столкнулся с такой задачей.
Имеется список со строками, так же имеется список с числами. Задача заключается в том, что список с числами нужно сделать ключами списка со строками. При этом размер обоих массивов одинаковый и после создания словаря отсортировать его по ключам.
К примеру дано:

```
arr1 = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']
arr2 = [6,2,3,7,8]
```

В результате должен получится такой словарь

```
arr3 = {6:'value1', 2: 'value2', 3:'value3', 7:'value4', 8:'value5'}
```

После этого нужно отсортировать словарь по ключам по возрастанию.
Вопрос в том можно ли сделать такой алгоритм как можно лаконичней и короче?

Comment: Ну тут просто цикл для создания или заполнения словаря, потом сортировка. Куда уж лаконичнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr1 = ['valu1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']
arr2 = [6,2,3,7,8]
dct = dict(sorted(zip(arr2, arr1)))
print(dct)
```

Тут сортировка происходит перед созданием словаря. Но словари в принципе не умеют сортироваться. Можно сделать

```
dct = dict(sorted(dct.items()))
```

Ну тут сортируются кортежи, из которых заново создаëтся словарь.